# Why my WordPress Posts are accessible from any directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My permalink structure is **example.com.com/sample-post/**. But when i access my posts with example.com.com/nodirectory/sample-post/, instead of redirect, the /sample-post/ is opened on the browser with permlaink example.com.com/nodirectory/sample-post/.

Comment: It should redirect to example.com/sample-post. I've tried this on my WordPress site. With URL imttoo.com/nodirectory/top-5-youtube-networks/ it redirects to imttoo.com/top-5-youtube-networks/

Comment: but not on my blog??

Comment: what is your domain name?